# How masking is applied in bitwise_operation in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I was looking at the documentation of the OpenCV and found something which I couldn't understand. I've tried to find it on the web but couldn't find anything satisfying. Can you please help me in a line of code?
Here is the code:

```
# Load two images
img1 = cv.imread('messi5.jpg')
img2 = cv.imread('opencv-logo-white.png')
# I want to put logo on top-left corner, So I create a ROI
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
roi = img1[0:rows, 0:cols ]
# Now create a mask of logo and create its inverse mask also
img2gray = cv.cvtColor(img2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv.threshold(img2gray, 10, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv.bitwise_not(mask)
# Now black-out the area of logo in ROI
img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)
# Take only region of logo from logo image.
img2_fg = cv.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)
# Put logo in ROI and modify the main image
dst = cv.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
img1[0:rows, 0:cols ] = dst
cv.imshow('res',img1)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I actually don't understand are these two lines

> img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)
>
> img2_fg = cv.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)

What these lines actually do and how the masking will be applied?

If anyone can explain the masking being applied in the bitwise_and operation that would be really helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html).

The mask is the black and white image of the OpenCV logo, it was created from applying a threshold to the OpenCV logo.

The `bitwise_and` operation is a [logical and operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

In this case, it is taking two 8 bit numbers representing a pixel and applying the and operation on those numbers.

[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14) describes what this function does.

Since the first two parameters are the same (both `roi` or `img2`) the result would be the same image if a mask wasn't being used.  Places, where the mask is black, are left the same as the destination image.

In this case, no destination image is provided, so OpenCV allocates a black image (zeros) for the destination image used in the function (this is generally how OpenCV works when a function is not provided with a Matrix).

Specifically `img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)` will create a black matrix used in the function which later becomes the output `img1_bg`. Only the parts of this black image that match up with white pixels in `mask_inv` are filled with the pixels from `roi`.This means that in the mask_inv where there are white pixels. the roi value will be copied in the pure black image generated by the function in the corresponding coordinate.

Similarly `img2_fg = cv.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)` will create a black matrix used in the function which later becomes the output `img2_fg`. Only the parts of this black image that match up with white pixels in `mask` are filled with the pixels from `img2`.

This makes it so when you add `img1_bg` and `img2_fg` the result is only the part of each image that is masked.

Personally, I think this is a confusing use of `bitwise_and`.  I think to demonstrate the function of `bitwise_and` it would be clearer to remove the mask parameter as follows: `img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi, mask_inv)`.  This would give the same result, zeros where the mask is black, and the ROI values where it is not since the mask has pixels that are all ones or all zeroes.

If you don't care to demonstrate `bitwise_and` usage, in python I think it would be clearer to use logical indexing as follows:

```
output = np.zeros(img1.shape, np.uint8)
output[mask_inv] = img1_bg[mask_inv]
output[mask] = img2_fg[mask]
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more "The black matrix is then filled in with either roi or img2 in the mask_inv or mask white pixels respectively, with the rest being black"

Comment: And please upvote if you think this question maybe helpful for other user in the future.

Comment: I edited my post to help clarify. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: What about this line "Only the parts of this black image that match up with white pixels in mask_inv are filled with the pixels from roi"? How black image which has each pixel value equals to zero matches with white pixels in the mask?

Comment: The black image is the same size as the mask.  The coordinates of the pixel in the pure black image match up with the coordinates of the pixel in the mask image.

Comment: but in the pure black image, there won't be any white pixel. So, how they would match?

Comment: the coordinates match.  The coordinates refer to the row and column of the pixel.  The top-left corner is (0,0), the bottom-right corner will be (width-1,height-1).  Both images are the same width and height, so each pixel has a corresponding pixel in the matching image.

Comment: so you meant to say that in the mask where there are white pixels. the roi value will be copied in the pure black image in the corresponding coordinate.

Comment: that is what I mean.